# Android get CheckBox key name from CompoundButton of the OnCheckedChangeListener

Tags: android

I am using interface `OnCheckedChangeListener` and `onCheckedChanged` method is fired when i click on checbox.

But i have 10 checkboxes. How can i get the name of clicked checkbox in CompoundButton. I think that `CompoundButton` has all necesarry values but I don't know how to get this value

For example:

```
<CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/cb_mute_all_sounds"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:key="nm_mute_all_sounds" />
```

how to get now the key name as `nm_mute_all_sounds` in `CompoundButton`?

```
     @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
buttonView.
```

or how do you know which one I clicked?

Comment: I don't see attribute like android:key for check box or for any others

Comment: CompoundButton has all the values I think but I can not find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ID directly:

```
 public void onCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton theView, boolean checked) {
   if (theView.getId() == R.id.nm_mute_all_sounds) {
     // do stuff
   }
 }
```

Comment: "or how do you know which one I clicked?" It's better to use the IDs. Since they are compiled, if the IDs change the code will break, forcing the developer to update the IDs. Using a string key is much more brittle.